# Can pseudo code be used be used as a clarification to the problem in addition to the code you want reviewed?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

So I believe in not submitting pseudo code to be reviewed or as an answer and it is clearly decided against here. I had a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31765/switching-directions-in-iterating-2d-arrays) about code where I knew of an alternative approach to solve the problem but it was not the code I wished to have reviewed so I added the pseudo for the alternative method because of a request to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is the intent, then I see no problems with it.  Anything to aid in a review is encouraged, as long as it doesn't create clutter (such as excessive bad comments).  We don't condemn pseudocode outright-- we just don't want to *review* it.  You probably won't have very many users asking to see pseudocode (in particular), but it couldn't hurt to add it as long as it may help.  Just don't add it for the heck of it.